# How can I send all the checked item into php using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

How can I send all the checked item into php using AJAX. The info I expect to send including checkbox id and checkbox inner text. e.g. If I check box1 and box2, it could save the useful info into Data then sent to php when I click submit.

I try to use `serialize()` in javascript, however the Date has always been "".

```
var Data = $('#myform').serialize();
```

Please notice that I don not expect realtime respond when I check each box. I just wanna send the entire checked list after I click "submit".

```html
<form class="myform" id="myform" action="add.php">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox[]" id="1"> 1
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox[]" id="2"> 2
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox[]" id="3"> 3
  <input type="submit" class="add" id="add" name="add">
<form>
```

Comment: Are you sending your form via form post/get? Or ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can use this code

```
var checkBox= new Array();
$("input:checked").each(function() {
   data['checkBox[]'].push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: If I have two forms formA and formB, both have input checkbox. $("input:checked") will get all checked items from these two forms. How to deal with these two checked list respectively. e.g. I just wanna get the checked item list from formB.

Comment: here i am using name attribute, so you can give different name of check box for formA as well as fromB